# pdf signer in php using SetaPDF-Signer

Tags: php, pdf

my problem is that i cannot move to the last statement that is the echo statement. the pdf signer gives a correct output but the execution stops at the line '$signer->sign($module);'

how can i move to the next statement that is the echo statement

my code is given below...

```
require_once('SetaPDF-Signer/library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php');

// configure the temporary writer
SetaPDF_Core_Writer_TempFile::setTempDir('SetaPDF-Signer/demos');

// create a writer
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('235.pdf', true);
// create a new document instance
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename(
    'SetaPDF-Signer/235.pdf', $writer
);

// create a signer instance
$signer = new SetaPDF_Signer($document);

// set some signature properties  
$signer->setReason('needs to provide this ');
$signer->setLocation('needs to provide this');

// create a signature module
$module = new SetaPDF_Signer_Signature_Module_OpenSsl();
// load the certificate
$certificate = file_get_contents('xxxxxxxxx.pem');
$module->setCertificate($certificate);
$module->setPrivateKey(array($certificate, 'xxxxxxxxxx' /* no password */));

// sign the document and send the final document to the initial writer
$signer->sign($module);


echo "welcome";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose another writer instance, that will not automatically send the resulting document to the clients browser. E.g.:

```
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File('path/to/235.pdf');
```

instead of

```
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('235.pdf', true);
```

An overview of all available writer classes in SetaPDF is available [here](http://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/readers-and-writers/).